# apt-get install for different python versions

Tags: python

I have Ubuntu 10.04 with python2.6 by default. I have installed python2.7. When I want to install python packages with apt-get python- it gets installed to python2.6. How can I make it to install to python2.7, is there any options?

I have considered using `easy_install-2.7` but not all packages are supported. For example python-torctl. I am more interested in binding python2.7 with apt-get install.

Comment: Cross posted on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960805/apt-get-install-for-different-python-versions

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have all versions of Python that are supported by Python-Markdown installed, you need to [Take a look at this](http://achinghead.com/installing-multiple-versions-python.html) and  [This](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/05/how-to-install-and-manage-different-versions-of-python-in-linux/)

Comment: But I have already installed python2.7 there was no problem with installation, I am just interested in apt-get install